# Which folder should I transfer when deploying xampp to cloud with FTP?

Tags: php, ftp, xampp, google-cloud-platform

This is my first time deploying xampp server to cloud. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.apachefriends.org/docs/hosting-xampp-on-google.html) and everything is straight forward. But when it comes which folder to transfer I found it unclear. I transferred my xampp folder(to the htdocs folder in the remote cloud) containing the whole server files but when I try to access it through the internet the .php files do not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local project you have on your machine should be serving from `htdocs` directory on your machine. You have to sync that with the directory online. Follow the steps:

- Login in the server using FTP and go to `/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/`
- Copy contents of this remote folder into your machine as a backup
- Now open your local XAMPP folder. On windows its `c:xampp/htdocs` on linux `/home/user/www`
- Copy all the files in `htdocs` directory from your local machine to server

This should do it.